# Unable to retrieve random DB values In JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, I am able to connect to DB and retrieve DB values.
I can view the DB_Value using variable which I specified in JDBC request(Variable Names field).
Example: with index of column value as CustomerID_**1**

I used BeanShell Sampler with below code:

${__BeanShell(vars.put("p_CustomerID_New","${CustomerID_1}"))}

with this p_CustomerID_New i am able to get db value and that works.

Now i have another random variable to replace above "1" with random numbers, so that i will be able to use different customers from DB and substitute in my API_Request.

When i use beanshell script with ${CustomerID}_${randomNo}, it only stores random number and CustomerID is not retrieved.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any scripting at all, just to for [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function combination:

```
${__V(CustomerID_${__Random(1,${CustomerID_#},)},)}
```

According to [JDBC Request Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) the following variables are getting generated when you run a Select statement:

- `Customer_ID_#` - number of rows returned
- `Customer_ID_1` - value from the first row
- `Customer_ID_2` - value from the second row
- etc.

So

- `${__Random(1,${CustomerID_#},)}` function returns a random number between 1 and the number of returned rows
- `__V()` function evaluates the generated expression and returns the random value

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Going forward be informed that since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: Dmitri :-) U are always perfect.. thanks much.. now i am observing another issue, can u guide for this as well?

like customer id, i have three other values needs to be retrieved from Database, and all are inter-linked to each other.

If i use same technique for those three values then, instead of first set of columns, retrieving, random columns

Example: Column 1 has values A,D ; Column 2 has values B,E ; Column 3 has values C,F

Expected result is to retrieve for one iteration values as  A,B,C
but receiving AEC, DBC, AEF etc...

Answer (score 0):

First of all using of Beanshell is deprecated and it is not a recommended to use it in Testplan.

It is recommended to use JSR223 pre/post-processor according to your needs.
I used pre-processor for the sampler - it works well

```
import java.util.Random;
Random rand = new Random();

def varName= "CustomerID_";
int randBoundary = rand.nextInt(100);// this will generate values between 0-100
varName = varName + randBoundary;
vars.put("p_CustomerID_New", vars.get(varName));
```

You can use this sample code and modify according to your requirements.

Comment: Its not working for me. after using above code, if i check for the value of p_CustomerID_New, its empty

Comment: Did you define parameter CustomerID_1